# Reading serialized file - java

Tags: java, file, serialization, binary, hex

So I am having problems reading from a serialized file.

More specifically, I have serialized an object to a file written in a hexadecimal format. The problem occurs when I want to read one line at a time from this file. For example, the file can look like this:

aced 0005 7372 0005 5465 7374 41f2 13c1

215c 9734 6b02 0000 7870

However, the code underneath reads the whole file (instead of just the first line). Also, it automatically converts the hexadecimal data into something more readable: ¬ísrTestAòÁ

```
....
try (BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        read(file);
    } catch ...
....
public static void read(BufferedReader in) throws IOException{
    String line = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(line); // PROBLEM: This prints every line

    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine if I have a normal text file with some random words, it only prints the first line. My guess is the problems lies in the serialization format. I read somewhere (probably the API) that the file is supposed to be in binary (even though my file is in hexadecimal??).

What should I do to be able to read one line at a time from this file?

**EDIT:** I have gotten quite a few of answers, which I am thankful for. I never wanted to deserialize the object - only be able to read every hexadecimal line (one at a time) so I could analyze the serialized object. I am sorry if the question was unclear.

Now I have realized that the file is actually not written in hexadecimal but in binary. Further, it is not even devided into lines. The problem I am facing now is to read every byte and convert it into hexadecimal. Basically, I want the data to look like the hexadecimal data above.

**UPDATE:**

immibis comments helped me solve this.
"Use FileInputStream (or a BufferedInputStream wrapping one) and call read() repeatedly - each call returns one byte (from 0 to 255) or -1 if there are no more bytes in the file. This is the simplest, but not the most efficient, way (reading an array is usually faster)"

Comment: *"For example, the file can look like this:"* With a plain text editor or a hexadecimal editor?

Comment: If you're using serialisation to write the file, why aren't you using it to read the file also? That's what it's there for ...

Comment: @johnchen902 With sublime text 2, whatever category that falls into.

Comment: @hokosha Doesn't help, it can read both.

Comment: Is there \n in your serialized file?

Comment: @AntonH I do not want to deserialize the object, if that is what you are talking about. I only want to read each line from the file. I am later planning on doing something with the hexadecimal code.

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD Well, I have mentioned everything I can read from the file above. Java serialized the object, so I do not know if there are any "\n".

Comment: Serialisation doesn't add any newline values, so it's possible that the entire file is just one line long, and by reading and printing one line, you print the entire file.

Comment: @AntonH Yeah, that makes sense. I also tried to open the file with notepad and got a different result: ¬ísrTestAòÁ (instead of hexadecimal). Now the problem is that I actually want it in hexadecimal. So I will probably have to convert the whole file to hexadecimal, right?

Comment: I think you have to consider the file as binary format and not text.
Notepad and println show to you characters because they interpret hexadecimal.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246360/java-loading-binary-files) is another Stack overflow post who spoke about binary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file does not contain hexadecimal text and is not separated into lines.

Whatever program you are using to edit the file is "helpfully" converting it into hexadecimal for you, since it would be gibberish if displayed directly.

If you are writing the file using `ObjectOutputStream` and `FileOutputStream`, then you need to read it using `ObjectInputStream` and `FileInputStream`.

Comment: Alright, thank you. The thing though is that if the file contained this:
1st line: "Hi my name"
2nd line: "consists of three"
3rd line: "Letters"
The code above would print "Hi my name". Now, this isn't the case for the serialized file, it would print everything since it is in binary. So is there any way I can convert the file into hexadecimal instead of binary, so the file would always look like the above? I do not want to deserialize it, only be able to read each line. For example: "Ah, this line contains aced".

Comment: The file *doesn't* contain the letters "aced". The file starts with a byte 172 followed by a byte 237, which happen to be "AC" and "ED" in hexadecimal. You could read each byte and convert it to hexadecimal yourself.

Comment: Also, the file is not divided into lines. Whatever program you used to view the file split it up into lines in some way to make it fit on your screen. The line splitting isn't actually in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I am starting to realise the main problem. Do you know how I can read each byte then?

Comment: Use `FileInputStream` (or a `BufferedInputStream` wrapping one) and call `read()` repeatedly - each call returns one byte (from 0 to 255) or -1 if there are no more bytes in the file. This is the simplest, but not the most efficient, way (reading an array is usually faster)

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make any sense. Serialized data is binary. It doesn't contain lines. You can't read lines from it. You should either read bytes, with an `InputStream,` or objects, with an `ObjectInputStream.`

Comment: I am sorry if the question seems weird. The thing is that I do not want to deserialize the object. I only wish to analyze the serialized file by reading every line, one at a time. Now I am realising that the file is actually NOT written in hexadecimal, so my question is, is there any way to convert the file into hexadecimal, so it would always look like the data in the main post?
I hope this clarifies a few things.

Comment: Why? Why do you think you need hex as opposed to binary? And what on earth are you gong to do with it?

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is true. I probably do not need it in hexadecimal. How do I read every byte then? To be honest, it is just a small little project I am doing to understand serialization and programming better. If you serialize an object there is a lot of information about that object hidden in the serialized file. So I want to analyze the file to see what data I can find.

Comment: So look at it. You don't need to write any code at all. Just use a hex editor, as you seem to be already doing, and study the protocol chapter of the specification.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have been doing but I thought to go one step further and create a simple "Serialized file decipherer", that basically tries to find all the hidden data in the file. So let's say you only have the file (no code or anything) and you want to understand what the file says. Nothing too fancy but it is a way for me to practise programming.

Comment: Forget about it. You can't read serialized files in general unless you are deserializing them. The reason is, as you should know from the specification, that any class can write anything it likes as its own serialized state, and only the class knows how to deserialize it. Try something easier.